# How to get coordinates of scroll on RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

I'm writing an very simple text editor with highlight of digitis, in some keywords and special chars. Now I'm implementing the line numbers,for do it I'm using a `ListView`, that is updated to each new line added.

The problem that is when I down  scroll using cursor,the number of lines is not updated,then if I jump to 30 line, the `listView` remains where it was, in line 10, for example for this reason I'm looking an way to get scroll the coordinates of `RichTextBox` to sincronize with scroll of listView.

Comment: You are scrolling down in the RichTextBox?   How are you getting line number now?

Comment: @BalamBalam: I set lines numbers,with base on this: `var textRange = new TextRange(TextInput.Document.ContentStart, TextInput.Document.ContentEnd);
            string[] lines = textRange.Text.Split('\n');`and call `.Length`, and then: `for (int i = 1, count = lines.Length; i < count; i++)
            {
                Rows.Items.Add(i);
            }`  it's called on TextChanged of `RichTextBox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of developing your own text editor, you can try [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/#SharpDevelop4x)'s editor. You don't have to fully install it. Just download its source and compile only `ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit`

It has a property `ShowLineNumbers` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
TextPointer textPointer = MyRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(8);
if (textPointer != null)
{
    MyRichTextBox.CaretPosition = textPointer;

    MyRichTextBox.Focus();
    MyRichTextBox.Selection.Select(MyRichTextBox.CaretPosition, MyRichTextBox.CaretPosition);
}
```